# Retrofit POJOs are with serializable - should i convert to parcelable

Tags: android, retrofit, parcelable

I have an existing android project. In it I have at least 20 Retrofit POJOs classes for responses that have been created and are serializable.  Realizing that in android serializing is slow, would it be wise to change the bigger POJOs to parcelable ? would it effect retrofit in any way ?

Comment: Well we had the same issue and started using Parceler (library) and it made our lives so much easier and faster.

Comment: Retrofit does not even care whether your objects implement `Serializable` or not (or rather, Gson does not care and since you don't say otherwise I assume that you are Retrofit with Gson) - so no, it won't change Retrofit's behaviour or speed in any way if  you switch the POJOs to `Parcelable`.

Comment: you can create an answer as i've accepted this as true after researching. .

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't change retrofit's speed (for better or worse) if you switch to `Parcelable`.